# How to select all orders from a specific customer using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I'm facing a problem when trying to select all the orders of a given client acessing the website and display them on the screen trhough a table. The problem is that the array that is being returned has the values ​​of the orders tripled (each order appears 3 times and not one).

```
$query = "SELECT orders.orderID, orders.date, products.name, products.price
   FROM ((orders
   INNER JOIN customers ON orders.userID = ?)
   INNER JOIN products ON orders.productID = products.productID)";

   $stm = $pdo->prepare($query);
   $stm->execute([$_SESSION['id']]); // The ID of the customer using the website
   $orders_array = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

My database has a customers table, a products table and an orders table. 
I wanted the associative array to have the order id, product name, order date, and price, and in fact, all of this is being returned. However, it is being selected 3 times for each order. 
I've searched on the internet for examples like this, but I could not find any examples that fit what I want. Does anyone have any idea why the values ​​are tripled

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JOIN` is not correct. The `ON` clause needs to relate columns in two tables.

Since you're not selecting anyting from the `customers` table, you don't need that in the query at all.

```
SELECT orders.orderID, orders.date, products.name, products.price
FROM orders
INNER JOIN products ON orders.productID = products.productID
WHERE orders.userID = ?
```

if you did want to include customer information, it would be:

```
SELECT customer.name, orders.orderID, orders.date, products.name, products.price
FROM orders
INNER JOIN customer ON order.userID = customer.userID
INNER JOIN products ON orders.productID = products.productID
WHERE customer.userID = ?
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved my issue. It seems that my query was poorly structured.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM Customer
ORDER BY Nama_Customer;

SELECT * FROM Customer
ORDER BY Nama_Customer DESC;

SELECT * FROM Pasok
ORDER BY Jumlah_Pasok;

SELECT * FROM Pasok
ORDER BY Jumlah_Pasok DESC;

SELECT * FROM Supplier
WHERE Nama_Supplier NOT LIKE '%tron';

SELECT * FROM Customer
WHERE Kode_Customer='J-001'
OR Kode_Customer='B-002';

SELECT * FROM Customer
WHERE Kode_Customer IN ('J-001','B-002');

SELECT Nama_Customer FROM Customer
WHERE Kode_Customer IN ('J-001','B-002')
ORDER BY Nama_Customer;

Comment: Please can you explain your solution and what you did?